# How can I add hard drive to Qemu?

Tags: hard-drive, qemu, pci

I am writing an OS and booting it from floppy. I wrote tool to look for all PCI devices but there is no hard drive. How can I add it to see it in the list of PCI devices?

I tried to run it like

qemu-system-x86_64 -fda os-image.bin -machine accel=hvf -drive file=t.img,format=raw
but there is no hard drive in the list.